# How do I prevent my menu div element to not overlay the footer div element?

Tags: css

[image]

This is how it looks like.  How do I make my footer to display only to the right side?

This is my css code for the left menu box:

```
#left
{
    width:200px;
    height: 1920px;
    position:fixed;
    background-color:#4A4A4A;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

This is the footer:

```
footer
{
    padding:5px;
    background: #fff;
    color: steelblue;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 15px 2px #CCC;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing position:fixed; from your #left properties. A fixed element will not load on the same plane as a default (position:relative) element.